# Comparing the elements of two Arrays of same type

Tags: java

```
 Student[] arr1 = { new Student(111, "bbbb", "london"), new 
 Student(131, "aaaa", "nyc"), new Student(121, "cccc", "jaipur") };

Student[] newArr = {  new Student(131, "aaaa", "nyc"), new 
Student(111, "bbbb", "london"), new Student(121, "cccc", "jaipur") };
```

Comparing these two, using the same equals method provided in the link, why are they not equal? The arrays both still contain the same elements....

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {         
        // typecast obj to Student so that we can compare students
        Student s = (Student) obj;

        return this.rollno == s.rollno && this.name.equals(s.name)
                                && this.address.equals(s.address);
}
```

This is the equals function that was provided in the link [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-arrays-equals-java-examples/)

Comment: Where and how are you calling equals?

Comment: Why do you believe they are equal?

Comment: im just following the code thats in the geeksforgeeks link. My main concern is simply when im comparing the two arrays posted above the code why they aren't equal. It figured since it contains the same elements but the index comparison is different it should still return true but apparently thats not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to read the doc to get the answer.

[Arrays::equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-):

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one
>   another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain
>   the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements
>   in the two arrays are equal. Two objects e1 and e2 are considered
>   equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)). **In other words, the
>   two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same
>   order**. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are
>   null.

emphasis mine.

Comment: The emphasized wording isn't very precise: saying "same" could be misinterpreted as `==`, as in JUnit `isSame`. I prefer two sentences before.